# How can a link open a window in same page using JQuery? It works in Javascript as shown

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>

<title>Open Div from Link</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" />

<style type="text/css">

/*<![CDATA[*/
body
{
  background-color:#aaaaff;
}

#one
{
  position:absolute;
   top:80px;
   left:40px;
}

object
{
  width:980px; 
  height:660px; 
  border:solid 1px #000000;
}
/*//]]>*/

</style>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

//<![CDATA[
// written by: Coothead
  function updateObjectIframe(which) {
    document.getElementById('one').innerHTML = '<'+'object id="foo" name="foo" type="text/html" data="'+which.href+'"><\/object>';
}

//]]>

</script>
</head>


<body>

<div id="one">
<object id="foo" name="foo" type="text/html" data="http://www.w3schools.com/"></object>
</div>

<div>
<a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="updateObjectIframe(this); return false;">Retreive Existing Records</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If it works in JavaScript, it works in jQuery, except without necessitating the jQuery library.

Comment: Could you offer some JQuery code showing how this can be written? I see some examples in JQ for opening in a new window but not within a div in the same window.  Sonny5

Answer (score 0):

Make from scratch using a div is too costly, because you need to implement all the handling of dialog (drag, drop, close)
You can use an gui lib, like [jQuery UI](http://www.jqueryui.com), or an [jquery plugin.](http://plugins.jquery.com/search/node)